# Does a completely arbitrary unbounded operator in a separable Hilbert space have a spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Spectral theory in Hilbert spaces usually starts with the assumption that an unbounded operator is closed. This is a restriction applied to the class of all unbounded operators in a separable Hilbert space. Why is it needed? Can't one define the resolvent operator and the split of $\mathbb{C}$ into the resolvent and the spectral sets if the operator is unbounded and completely arbitrary?

I do not recall reading a justification of studying spectral theory only for closed operators.

Answer (score 0):

If the operator $T$ is bijective with a bounded inverse, then its graph satisfies
$$
\Gamma(T)=\{(x,Tx)\mid x\in D(T)\}=\{(T^{-1}y,y)\mid y\in H\}.
$$
The RHS is (up to a flip of the coordinates) the graph of $T^{-1}$, which is closed. Thus $T$ must be closed.

Now assume that $\lambda\in \rho(S)$. If we apply the result from the first paragraph to $S-\lambda$, we obtain that $S-\lambda$ is closed. From this it is not hard to conclude that $S$ itself must be closed.

In other words, you can define the spectrum of an operator that is not closed, but it will be all of $\mathbb{C}$. That is why spectral theory is not very interesting if the operator is not closed.

Comment: In your third paragraph you assume that the definition of $\rho(S)$ assumes that the inverse of $S-\lambda$ is defined on all of $H$. Not everyone uses that as the definition. For example Yosida is content with the range of $S-\lambda$ just being dense and the (densely defined) inverse being continuous. Then, one gets the implication that if $S$ is closed, then $(S-\lambda)^{-1}$  is defined everywhere. In this case closedness is not a consequence, but a convenient assumption.

Comment: 1. I do not understand how can an operator be bijective and unbounded at the same time. 2. I do not see how the graph of $T^{-1}$ is closed.

Comment: An operator is bijective if it is injective and surjective. Boundedness doesn't come into play here. As a concrete example, if $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function on $(X,\mu)$, then multiplication by $f+1$ is bijective on $L^2(X,\mu)$. But it is bounded if and only if $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Every bounded operator on a Banach space is closed. As $T^{-1}$ is assumed to be bounded, it must be closed.